# making a queue of animations

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

So I searched for a solution and I didn't find something...

I have an application that use Storyboard for animations, and a button that create the animation and start it. looks like this:

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            //properties
        };

        sb = new Storyboard();//sb is the Storyboard
        sb.Children.Add(animation);

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, myControl.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));

        sb.Begin(this);
```

The problem is that when I click the button while the animation still running, it restart the animation, and I want it to "add it to the order" so when the animation finished it starts again over and over, the amount of times I clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change a storyboard that's already running I suggest you instead use just a list of animations.
Or storyboards if you need some functionality in storyboard like animating several things at once.

You can then add them to a list ( or queue even ).
Subscribe to the completed event of each.
Keep a currentIndex pointer so you know which one is running.
When the completed event is hit, unhook your event handler from the one just finished, hook the next one. Begin the next storyboard.